# ORACLE file I/O withouth explicit flushing on 10g and 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

what happens, if I open a file (`foo := utl_file.fopen(...` ), write multiple times to a file ( `utl_file.put_line (foo,bar`) ) and close it ( `utl_file.fclose(foo)` ) **without any flushing**?

Is there a difference between the versions 10g and 11g? 
Is the output deterministic?

Thank you

Edit 1: I am asking because we got some missing characters in a huge output file at some points where the 7FFF (= 32767) byte is full and the 32768th byte would be written. This error exists only since the update from 10g to 11g. The error in the code might be a missing flush, but we don't get any exceptions and it was working before the update. The issue is not with every 32768th byte.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to `flush` or are you just curious?

Comment: We had some buggy code, which worked without flushing on 10g but on 11g we get this error. So I tried to figure out what caused the error. We tried to write two files (one with flush, one without) but the error is in both files

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for

10g http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003326

11g http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70908

and

12c http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/u_file.htm#i1003326

> If there is buffered data yet to be written when FCLOSE runs, then you may receive a WRITE_ERROR exception when closing a file.

So you should call `utl_file.fflush(foo);` before closing.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I added some more text for clarification. Please see "Edit 1".